# is it possible to filter a rest api endpoint by using a registered rest field?

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

I added a rest field into a custom post type endpoint as following:

```
function artists_per_building() {
   register_rest_field( 'building',
  'artists',
array(
    'get_callback'  => 'rest_get_users_per_building',
    'update_callback'   => null,
    'schema'            => null,
  )
 );
 }
 add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'artists_per_building' );

function rest_get_users_per_building( $request ) {

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
array(
    'role'          => 'artists_role',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'  => 'AND',
        array( 
            'key'     => 'building',
            'value'   => $request["id"],
          )
      )
   ) 
);
   return count($user_query->get_results());
}
```

Now I would like to order by artists, is this possible?

Comment: Thinking you'd be able to handle the ordering of results in `rest_get_users_per_building()`

Comment: Unless you want to order `building` resources returned from the `/buildings` endpoint by the `artists` field? If that is the case, it sounds to me like this new `artists` field is a list of users... what would be the intended ordering behavior, in order to sort a list of buildings by their lists of artists? Would it be by the number of artists each has?

Comment: sorry for not explaining that part, artists is actually a number which is the amount of artists that have selected a specific building. So I'm looking to sort by the amount of artists but still unsuccessful @bosco

Comment: Ah alright - well that makes things slightly easier in any case. How do you determine the `artists` count - is it stored as post meta for the `building` post type per chance?

Comment: Ah hmm... That makes things more complicated, as ordering by a count produced by a separate query is not something that `WP_Query` itself is capable of.

Comment: I updated the post to show how I'm getting the amount of `artists` per `building`. Basically, each artists has a building as part of their meta. I'm not sure if I should store an artists list into the meta of `building` @bosco

Comment: I think such a thing will be necessary - but I'll include it as part of my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, yes, but for this specific use-case I think you'll need to do a little more legwork than usual.

### Add `artist_count` meta to `building` posts

In principal we'd be trying to tell the `WP_Query` responsible for retrieving `building`s to "orderby number of artists," but since many `artist`s are associated with a single `building` by way of an `artist`'s user meta only, there's no direct way to perform that ordering through a `WP_Query` (short of modifying the actual SQL).

I think the easiest way to mitigate this situation would be to add the artist count as post meta to each building and update that count as necessary. We can patch that in to your existing functionality regardless of how you're currently setting roles and assigning buildings by hooking in to role and user meta changes:

```php
/**
 * Update buildings' artist_count meta and optionally a user's building meta.
 *
 * @param int      $user_id The ID of the user who's being assigned a new building.
 * @param int|null $new_building The ID of the user's new building, or `null` if the assignment is being removed.
 * @param int|null $old_building The ID of the user's previous building, or `null` if there wasn't one.
 * @param boolean  $update_user Whether or not to update the user's `building` meta.
 **/
function wpse391043_assign_artist_building( $user_id, $new_building = null, $old_building = null, $update_user = false ) {
  if( empty( $new_building ) && empty( $old_building ) )
    return;
  
  // Subtract one from the previous building's artist count, if applicable.
  if( ! empty( $old_building ) ) {
    $building_count = get_post_meta( $old_building, 'artist_count', true );

    update_post_meta(
      $old_building,
      'artist_count',
      empty( $building_count ) ? 0 : $building_count - 1
    );
  }

  // Add one to the new building's artist count, and set the user's new building meta if applicable.
  if( ! empty( $new_building ) ) {
    $building_count = get_post_meta( $new_building, 'artist_count', true );
  
    update_post_meta(
      $new_building,
      'artist_count',
      empty( $building_count ) ? 1 : $building_count + 1
    );

    if( $update_user )
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'building', $new_building );
  }
  else if( $update_user ) {
    // If there's no new building ID, remove the user meta.
    delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'building' );
  }
}

/**
 * When a user has building meta set with no previous value, increment the building's
 * artist_count meta.
 **/
function wpse391043_add_user_building_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $building_id ) {
  if( $meta_key !== 'building' )
    return;

  wpse391043_assign_artist_building( $user_id, $building_id );
}
add_action( 'add_user_meta', 'wpse391043_add_user_building_meta', 10, 3 );

/**
 * When a user's building meta changes, update both building's artist_count meta.
 **/
function wpse391043_update_user_building_meta( $meta_id, $user_id, $meta_key, $building_id ) {
  if( $meta_key !== 'building' )
    return;
  
  $old_building = get_user_meta( $meta_id, 'building', true );
  
  wpse391043_assign_artist_building( $user_id, $building_id, $old_building );
}
add_action( 'update_user_meta', 'wpse391043_update_user_building_meta', 10, 4 );

/**
 * Remove a user's building meta and update the building's artist_count meta if a user
 * looses the artists_role role.
 */
function wpse391043_update_user_role( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ) {
  if( $role === 'artists_role' || current( $old_roles ) !== 'artists_role' )
    return;
  
  $old_building = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'building', true );
  
  wpse391043_assign_artist_building( $user_id, null, $old_building, true );
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'wpse391043_update_user_role', 10, 3 );
```

With that in place, buildings' `artist_count` meta should now stay up-to-date with whatever changes to users' `building` meta are taking place; and `rest_get_users_per_building()` gets a nice performance boost in that now it only need look up one piece of post meta:

```php
function rest_get_users_per_building( $building ) {
  $artist_count = get_post_meta( $building['id'], 'artist_count', true );

  return empty( $artist_count ) ? 0 : $artist_count;
}
```

This will also benefit the actual `orderby` operation on the whole, as it does not need to calculate artist counts for every building each time such a request is made.

### Register the `artists` `orderby` REST parameter

Now we can use a [`rest_{post type}_collection_params`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/) filter in order to expose a new `artists` `orderby` param:

```php
/**
 * Add `artists` as an orderby parameter for the building REST controller.
 **/
function wpse391043_rest_building_params( $params ) {
  $params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'artists';
  return $params;
}
add_filter( 'rest_building_collection_params', 'wpse391043_rest_building_params' );
```

### Modify the REST `WP_Query` arguments to account for `orderby=artists`

And a `rest_{post type}_query` filter in order to factor that parameter in to the building post type query:

```php
/**
 * If `orderby` is `artists`, modify the query to order by `artist_count` meta.
 **/
function wpse391043_rest_building_query( $args, $request ) {
  $orderby = $request->get_param( 'orderby' );

  if( empty( $orderby ) || $orderby !== 'artists' )
    return $args;

  $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
  $args['meta_key'] = 'artist_count';

  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_building_collection_query', 'wpse391043_rest_building_query', 10, 2 );
```

After which, you should be able to order buildings by their `artist_count` meta using the new parameter:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/buildings?orderby=artists
```

### Synchronize current artist counts to the new meta

You might need to get the new `artist_count` meta set up on each building to reflect the current assignments, which could be done with a little loop which can you run once:

```php
function wpse391043_sync_building_artist_counts() {
  $building_counts     = []; // A mapping of building IDs to artist counts.
  $assigned_artist_ids = get_users(
    [
      'role'         => 'artists_role',
      'meta_key'     => 'building',
      'meta_compare' => 'EXISTS',
      'number'       => -1,
      'fields '      => 'ID',
    ]
  );

  foreach( $assigned_artist_ids as $user_id ) {
    $building_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'building' );

    if( empty( $building_id ) )
      continue;
    
    if( ! isset( $building_counts[ $building_id ] ) )
      $building_counts[ $building_id ] = 0;

    $building_counts[ $building_id ]++;
  }
    
  foreach( $building_counts as $building_id => $artist_count )
    update_post_meta( $building_id, 'artist_count', $artist_count );
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: haven't tested any of this code - use at your own peril. Will test later, if time allows.

Comment: you are amazing, thank you so much. This solved my problem and also taught me new things.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time thinking about this very problem, in different forms. Glad all that thinkin' could be of use :)